# Как открыть форму new. С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Проблема: Я решил сделать интерфейс. Сбоку которого есть кнопочки. При нажатии на кнопочку исполняется код, который переключает на дочернею форму. При переходе на другую дочернею форму по нажатию кнопочки загружается форма, и если хочешь вернутся на прошлую дочернею форму, то эта форма загружается заново. Повышается потребление ОЗУ и пропадают ведённые данные.
Вот кусок кода:

```
 public void openChildForm(Form childForm, object btnSender)
        {
            if (activeForm != null)
                activeForm.Hide();
            activeForm = childForm;
            childForm.TopLevel = false;
            childForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            childForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            panelChildForm.Controls.Add(childForm);
            panelChildForm.Tag = childForm;
            childForm.BringToFront();
            childForm.Show();
        }

 private void btnSettings_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            openChildForm(new Settings(), sender);
        }
```

Использовал hide и show, толку нет.

Comment: Форму чего? Укажите тег winforms или wpf, покажите код. Отредактируйте вопрос. Какие данные хотите сохранять, для чего? Искали ли вы решение, какие нашли варианты? Почему они вам не подошли? Пытались ли решить вопрос самостоятельно? Сейчас ваш вопрос похож на "у меня болит нога, как вылечить?".

Comment: Всё указал, теперь похоже на "Болит здесь, пробовал подорожник, не помогло, что делать?"

Comment: .NET Core или .NET Framework?

Comment: .NET Framework последней версии

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так как сложно разобраться с тем, что вы натворили в коде, приведу отдельный пример, как один из способов реализовать окно настроек.

- В главном окне `Form1` одна кнопка с именем `button1` и названием **Settings**, заданным в дизайнере
- Дочернее окно `Form2` будет вызываться как модальное, то есть будет блокировать доступ к основному окну, пока оно открыто
- `Form2` содержит 3 контрола `textBox1`, и 2 кнопки `button1` **OK**, и `button2` **Cancel**

Суть примера в том, что название главного окна можно поменять в окне настроек, сохранить или отменить сохранение настроек. При закрытии программы настроки сохраняются в XML файл **settings.xml** в каталоге с программой. При запуске программы соответственно оттуда загружаются, и если файла нет (например при первом запуске программы), то устанавливаются по умолчанию.

Класс настроек **Settings.cs**

```csharp
[Serializable]
public class Settings
{
    // здесь и задам значение по умолчанию
    public string WindowName { get; set; } = "My Application";
}
```

Далее, реализую окно настроек, при этом событие `Form.Load` в дизайнере привяжу к обработчику `Form2_Load`.

Далее на `button1` я назначаю в дизайнере `DialogResult.OK`, на `button2` - `DialogResult.Cancel`

**Form2.cs**

```csharp
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    // публично доступное свойство с настройками
    public Settings Settings { get; set; }

    // никогда не вставляйте свой код в конструктор формы
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // гружу настройки в TextBox здесь
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Settings.WindowName;
    }

    // А здесь записываю значение TextBox в настроки
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Settings.WindowName = textBox1.Text;
    }
}
```

Далее, главное окно `Form1`. События `Form.Load` и `Form.FormClosing` привязываю с обработчикам `Form1_Load` и `Form1_FormClosing` соовтетственно.

**Form1.cs**

```csharp
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // путь к файлу с настройками
    private readonly string _settingsFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "settings.xml");

    // сами настройки, которые я буду хранить в классе главного окна
    private Settings _settings;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // этот обработчик вызывается при запуске приложения
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSettings();
        ApplySettings();
    }

    // этот обработчик вызывается при закрытии приложения
    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveSettings();
    }

    // загрузить настройки их XML файла
    private void LoadSettings()
    {
        // если файл есть
        if (File.Exists(_settingsFilePath))
        {
            // гружу из него настройки
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(_settingsFilePath)) 
            {
                _settings = serializer.Deserialize(sr) as Settings;
            }
        }
        else
        {
             // если файла нет, просто создаю новые
            _settings = new Settings();
        }
    }

    // сохранить настройки в XML файл
    private void SaveSettings()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(_settingsFilePath))
        {
            serializer.Serialize(sw, _settings);
        }
    }

    // применить настройки к окну
    private void ApplySettings()
    {
        Text = _settings.WindowName;
    }

    // кнопка Settings открывает окно настроек
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 formSettings = new Form2 { Settings = _settings };
        if (formSettings.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            _settings = formSettings.Settings;
            ApplySettings();
        }
    }
}
```

Главный прикол состоит в том, что `XmlSerializer` сам превращает класс в `XML` файл (сериализует), и обратно (десереализует) автоматически.

Создайте этот пример у себя на базе нового Windows Forms приложения и потестируйте его. Окно настроек конечно создается заново каждый раз, но при закрытии оно корректно уничтожается (назначение `DialogResult` кнопке автоматически закрывает модальное окно, вызванное с помощью `ShowDialog()`). Хранить в памяти только необходимые данные - дешевле и проще, чем целое окно.

К тому же `ShowDialog()` - это удобно. Например дочернему окну можно задать в дизайнере свойство `StartPosition` значение `CenterParent`, и оно появится ровно по центру родительского окна.

Пробуйте, тестируйте.