# Почему поле во втором методе равно null, когда я в первом создал экземпляр класса

Tags: c#, winforms

```
    FTP ftp;
    public void ConnectFTP(string ip)
    {
        ftp = new FTP(ip);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ftp.ConnectionFTPAsync();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form = new Form2();
        form.ShowDialog();
        if (form.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            form.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

в методе button1_Click поле ftp = null. Не могу понять почему. ConnectFTP выполняется до button1_Click (он вызывается с другой формы перед ее закрытием). Если переместить ftp.ConnectionFTPAsync(); в ConnectFTP, то все будет хорошо.

код 2 формы:

```
            if (textBox1.Text != "")
        {
            if (textBox2.Text != null && textBox3.Text != "")
            {
                String ip, login, password;
                login = textBox2.Text;
                password = textBox3.Text;
                ip = textBox1.Text;
                ip = "ftp://192.168.0.105";
                Form1 form = new Form1();
                form.ConnectFTP(ip);
                this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
            }
        }
```

Comment: *ConnectFTP выполняется до button1_Click* - очевидно это ошибочное утверждение, либо, как вариант, где-то еще есть присвоение этому полю

Comment: У вас ошибка где то в другом месте. То, что вы показываете, этого недостаточно.

Comment: Это winforms? Добавьте соответствующий тег к вопросу. Покажите как вы создаете второе окно, и метод, где вызываете ConnectFTP.

Comment: Дайте угадаю, у вас что-то типа `Form1 form = new Form1(); form.ConnectFTP(ip);`? Если да, то вы вызываете метод не у существующего окна, о создаете экземпляр нового.

Comment: Дополнил код и добавил метку winforms

Comment: О, только комментарий написал, и вот оно. :) Посмотрите [этот вариант реализации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1134820/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83-new-%d0%a1/1134892#1134892).

Comment: Еще `Application.Exit()` можно просто заменить на `Close()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Самое простое для вас:**

1) Измените конструктор второй формы вот так

```csharp
private Form1 _form1;

public Form2(Form1 form) 
{
    _form1 = form;
}
```

2) Вызывайте второе окно вот так

```csharp
Form2 form = new Form2(this);
form.ShowDialog();
```

3) а обращайтесь к методу вот так

```csharp
_form1.ConnectFTP(ip);
```

При этом **обязательно уберите** вот эту строчку

```csharp
//Form1 form = new Form1();
```

Еще `Application.Exit()` можно просто заменить на `Close()`