# Как сделать так, чтобы код выполнялся с периодичностью, допустим каждые 3 дня

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть код, который выполняется в определенное время.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string date = Properties.Settings.Default.frequency; 
//тут хранится значение ДЕНЬ:ЧАС, то есть Периодичность:ВремяЗапуска
        string[] dates = date.Split(new char[] { ':' }); 
        try
        {
            int hour = Convert.ToInt32(dates[1]);
            if (hour == DateTime.Now.Hour)
            {
                Backup.Start(); //тут вызывается код который считывает файлы
//и закачивает их на сервер, так что выполнять это много раз нет смысла
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Ошибка", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Properties.Settings.Default.frequency = "00:00";
        }
    }
```

Мне нужно как-то сделать, чтобы он в любое время, допустим в первые 15 минут часа выполнился и ждал следующего дня. Тик у меня стоит 5 минут, не думаю что если я установлю минутный тик, то хорошо скажется на производительности. Но я в этом не разбираюсь, просто догадки. Я могу установить минутный тик и точное время, но я боюсь, что он может пропустить этот минутный миг) Будет неприятно. Также важно чтобы я мог установить периодичность. Например раз в 3 дня. Количество дней будет указано в переменной.

Comment: Задайте тик равный суткам. При необходимости, создайте второй таймер.

Comment: Если я задам тик равный суткам, то если компьютер будет выключен тик не будет идти до момента нового запуска программы? Или он вообще при запуске начнет сначала?

Comment: Так ваша программа не запущена постоянно? Обязательно укажите это в вопросе.

Comment: Я бы сохранял время, когда должно произойти очередное выполнение, в файл (настройки, БД). При запуске приложения считывал бы это время и запускал таймер с тиком (интервалом) равным `значение_из_файла - текущее_время`.

Comment: Естественно, при запуске приложения нужно проверять считанное из файла значение: возможно, время тика уже прошло. И реагировать соответственно.

Comment: Вам обязательно выполнять код в вашем приложении? Вы же можете, к примеру, настроить шедулер windows и запускать какую нить консольку раз в 3 дня

Comment: Программа будет стоять на автозапуске. Компьютер соответственно будет выключаться. (Программа которая делает резервные копии если что)

Comment: Думаю да, обязательно объявлять код в приложении.

Comment: Для такого есть планировщик задач. Вот тут есть примеры: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/win32/taskschd/using-the-task-scheduler  (на C++, но там всё через COM-интерфейсы, так что перенести на C# должно быть несложно).

Comment: Вам однозначно не надо для этого писать программу. За вас это уже сделали в Microsoft. Вот первая попавшаяся ссылка про [Планировщик заданий](https://www.comss.ru/page.php?id=4840). Такая штуковина присутствует в любой Windows. А если для Linux, то там она называется `cron`.

Comment: Если же вам принципиально написать свой велосипед, то показывайте весь код. Из одного `if` не понятно, как у вас там все сделано, и в какую сторону это можно доработать. Тики можете хоть каждую секунду сделать, это никак не скажется на производительности. Я даже больше скажу, даже если вы будете 100 раз в секунду делать `if (hour == DateTime.Now.Hour)`, это никак не скажется на производительности компьютера, точнее в реальности скажется, но вы этого не заметите, даже если специально будете за этим следить, насколько это малая величина.

Comment: Добавил код. Я думал программисты когда обучаются сначала изобретают велосипеды, а потом выдумывают что-то свое)

Comment: [Вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134892/373567), как записать класс с данными на диск в XML файл при выходе из программы и прочитать его при запуске. Велосипед, так велосипед, никто не возражает. `timer1.Stop()` не забудьте только вызвать при выходе из программы, а то могут быть сюрпризы в виде выполнения кода даже когда программа уже закрыта (на самом деле не закрыта, а висит в памяти).

Comment: По коду: `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", ...); }` - так вы будете знать, что за исключение случилось. А сейчас просто знаете, что случилось, а что случилось - не знаете.

Comment: `сначала изобретают велосипеды, а потом выдумывают что-то свое)` это одно и то же по сути :)

Answer (score 1):

Не ответ на ваш вопрос, но подсказка. Так как вы показали таймер, то и по таймеру.

[Вот пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134892/373567), как записать класс с данными на диск в XML файл при выходе из программы и прочитать его при запуске.

`timer1.Stop()` не забудьте только вызвать при выходе из программы, а то могут быть сюрпризы в виде выполнения кода даже когда программа уже закрыта (на самом деле не закрыта, а висит в памяти).

Для обучения, немного доработал ваш код. Сейчас пока идет бэкап, ваше приложение будет "висеть", это легко исправить с помощью асинхронности.

При таком условии выполнения, поставьте таймер раз в час. Иначе пока часы в ваших данных равны часам на часах, код будет выполняться, как вы написали, раз в 5 минут.

```csharp
bool isTimerRunning = false;

private async void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isTimerRunning) return; // защита от повторного запуска
    isTimerRunning = true;
    string date = Properties.Settings.Default.frequency; 

    if (int.TryParse(date.Split(":")[1], out int hour) && hour == DateTime.Now.Hour)
    {
        // label1.Text = "Выполняется резервное копирование";
        try
        {
            await Task.Run(() => Backup.Start());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            Properties.Settings.Default.frequency = "00:00";
        }
        // label1.Text = "Резервное копирование закончилось";
    }
    isTimerRunning = false;
}
```

`async/await` - очень мощная штука, почитайте про это. И заведите `StatusStrip` в интерфейсе, поместите туда `Label`, пишите туда что-то полезное для пользователя о работе приложения.

Чтобы улучшить планировщик на раз в несколько дней, при успешном запуске вам надо сохранять дату последнего запуска, и отсчитывать от нее дни.