# Как сохранить и загрузить значения множества CheckBox

Tags: c#

Есть много чекбоксов (не стандартных) а изменённый дизайн наследник от CheckBox.
Мне нужно каждое значение записать в файл .cfg, после загрузки формы загрузить каждое значение.
Как это можно реализовать ?

Comment: А что нового в задачу вносит тот факт, что ваши чекбоксы имеют нестандартный дизайн?

Comment: Winforms? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134892/373567 только там в примере xml, но я рекомендую лучше json

Comment: @aepot я бы предложил оставить xml, имхо json передача данных, xml - хранение. Если что xml руками поправить проще.

Comment: @VladD, работая с чекбоксами заметил что не работают методы для не стандартных чекбоксов, банальные включения и отключения всех чекбоксов по `linq` (вот для чекбоксов по дефолту работают) а если какой-то свой стиль, то нет.

Comment: @aepot, `Winforms` - Да.

Comment: @ZidoX: Это очень странно, приведите, пожалуста, код.